# Show that$∫_\mathbb{R} \hat{μ}(t)dν(t) =∫_\mathbb{R}\hat{ν}(t)dμ(t).$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

> Let $μ$ and $ν$ be two Borel probability measures on $\mathbb{R}$.  Show that$∫_\mathbb{R} \hat{μ}(t)dν(t) =∫_\mathbb{R}\hat{ν}(t)dμ(t).$

My Try:
Let $X$ be a random variable. Then $\hat{μ}(t)=\int_\mathbb{R} e^{itX}d\mu(X)$. 
So, $∫_\mathbb{R} \hat{μ}(t)dν(t) = ∫_\mathbb{R}\int_\mathbb{R} e^{itX}d\mu(X)dν(t)$. But after that I was stuck. This question may seem very easy to you but I have very little knowledge on Probability. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: do you know Fubini's Theorem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Fubini we have ,

$$\int_{\Bbb{R}}\widehat{\mu}(x)d\nu(x)=\int_{\Bbb{R}}\int_{\Bbb{R}}e^{itx}d\mu(t)d\nu(x)= \int_{\Bbb{R}}\int_{\Bbb{R}}e^{itx}d\nu(x)d\mu(t)=\int_{\Bbb{R}}\widehat{\nu}(t)d\mu(t)$$

Since, measures $\nu$ and $\mu$ have finite Total variation  since
$$\|\mu\|_1=\int_{\Bbb{R}}d\mu(x) = 1,~~~\int_{\Bbb{R}}d\nu(x) =\|\nu\|_1=1$$

Comment: I think you have mixed up $\mu$ and $\nu$

Comment: Yes thanks I have edited

Answer (score 4):

\begin{align*}
\int_{\bf{R}}\int_{\bf{R}}e^{itx}d\mu(x)d\nu(t)=\int_{\bf{R}}\int_{\bf{R}}e^{itx}d\nu(t)d\mu(x)=\int_{\bf{R}}\widehat{v}(t)d\mu(t)
\end{align*}
by Fubini Theorem.